# How can I dynamically pad a number in python f-strings?

Tags: python, f-string

I have an f-string like this:

```
f"foo-{i:03d}"
```

This is producing a filename for a file that I read in. The problem is sometimes there are hundreds of files, so the files are named like foo-001, foo-002, etc., but other times there are thousands, so the files are foo-0001 and 04d would be needed. Is there a way I can do this dynamically? For example, if I have the total number of files as a variable n, then I could do:

```
pad = len(str(n))
```

but then how do I use that pad variable in the f-string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nested f-string:

```
>>> pad = 4
>>> i = 1
>>> f"foo-{i:>0{pad}}"
'foo-0001'
```

Comment: In my opinion, nested f-strings tend to make the code harder to read.

Comment: Opinions differ. I find it much more readable than the alternatives.

Comment: Sure, but it's not obvious to understand for people who read your code unless they know advanced f-strings. It's much easier to get the idea behind the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an f-string, `str.zfill()` may be preferable:

```py
"foo-" + str(i).zfill( len(str(n)) )
```

Advantages:

- Cleaner syntax
- Available in older Python versions